# Проверка правильности кода

Tags: c++

> В городе N есть большой склад на котором существует 50000 различных
>   полок. Для удобства работников руководство склада решило заказать для
>   каждой полки табличку с номером от 00001 до 50000 в местной
>   типографии, но когда таблички напечатали, оказалось что печатный
>   станок из-за неисправности не печатал цифру 2, поэтому все таблички, в
>   номерах которых содержалась одна или более двойка (например, 00002 или
>   20202) — надо перепечатывать. Напишите программу, которая подсчитает
>   сколько всего таких ошибочных табличек оказалось в бракованной партии.

Мой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int num = 0, rez = 0, i1 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        num = i;
        while (num > 0)
        {
             if (num % 2 == 0)
             {
                 ++rez;
                 break;

             }
             num /= 10;
         }
    }
cout << rez << "\n";`
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Я нахожу только четные числа. Подскажите, как определить, есть ли в числе двойка.

Comment: 00004 будет посчитана, как поломанная, а поломанной являться не будет

Answer (score 3):

Найдем общее количество чисел, которые кончаются на 2. В общем случае это n/10, здесь 5000. Отбросим эти числа, останется 45000, причем у каждых 9 первые 4 цифры одинаковые. Получим рекуррентную формулу
f(n)=n/10+9*f(n/10)
Причем для однозначных чисел, например 5, f(5)=1
Написать такую программу очень просто, и работает быстро. Ответ должен получится 23756.

```
 int tab(int n)
{

    if( n>=2 && n<10) return 1;
    return n /10+9*f(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
         {
             ++rez;
             break;

         }
```

Так как Вы проверяте не является ли цифра цифрой 2, а четное ли само число, Ваш код не работает.
Замените на

```
if (num % 10 == 2)
         {
             ++rez;
             break;

         }
```

Такой вариант кода полностью рабочий, но не оптимальный для больших num.
Есть более быстрые способы считать кол-во таких чисел, но это совсем другая история.

Comment: Спасибо за правку так и есть не подумал.

Answer (score 1):

Решение не верно, то что число делится на 2 не означает, что 2 – его последняя цифра.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int num = 0, rez = 0, i1 = 0, cipher=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 50000; i++){
        num = i;
        while (num > 0){
            cipher = num % 10; //получаем последнюю цифру числа
            if (cipher  == 2){
                ++rez;
                break;
           }
           num /= 10; //отбрасываем последнюю цифру числа
        }
   }
  cout << rez << "\n";
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но если заменить if (num % 2 == 0) на 
 if (num % 10 == 2) всё будет работать так же как и вы сказали.

Comment: @НикитаНадточей я просто написал так, чтобы было понятней

Answer (score 0):

Тупо аналитически. У нас есть:

(50000 - 10*0) / 10 - последнее число двойка

(50000 - 10*1) / 10 - второе с конца число двойка

(50000 - 10*2) / 10 - третье с конца число двойка

(50000 - 10*3) / 10 - четвертое с конца число двойка

(50000 - 10*4) / 10 - пятое с конца число двойка

Их сумма даст ответ.

Решается очевидным циклом, но вообще должно бы решаться на бумажке, для такого программы не пишут.